# Repeated beeps when doing anything "intensive" i.e. Adobe or Resolve for longer than 10-15 minutes

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, adobe-after-effects

I have an ASUS Z10PE-D8 WS with a pair of Intel Xeon E5-2687W v3s running Windows 10 that starts beeping repeatedly after I run programs such as After Effects or Resolve for more than 10-15 minutes. The beeping continues even after I shut down the program and requires a full restart to reset.

My LED was reading 30, then it started reading 40, I turned off the fast startup option, and now I get a consistent AA. I can transfer files, play on the internet, install all the programs and plug ins and whatnot all day long, but if I try to get any actual work done, the thing beeps at me after about 10 minutes.

The beeping doesn't actually force me to stop doing my work. The computer continues to run the program that has angered it just fine. I could continue on my merry way and just slowly lose my mind (and possibly destroy my computer), but instead I've returned to my much slower machine that just crashes After Effects every 20 minutes (an issue for another day or never if I can get this other machine to be agreeable).

Comment: The next time you hear beeps, check the temperature at which all your components are running, maybe an overheating warning by the motherboard.

Comment: Also, LED was reading 30, what is 30, Celsius,motherboard-codes?

Comment: 30 is the LED code. According to my best googling, 30, 40, and AA are all codes that basically mean "everything's perfectly all right now. We're fine. We're all fine here, now, thank you."

Comment: Can you try and note down the way in which the beep sounds like 2 long beeps followed by 1 short one, basically just the pattern of the beep. Once you have the pattern check if it matches with one on this website https://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-beeps.htm  .

Comment: THANKS!! It's continuous short beeps, and I have tried searching for something to confirm what continuous short beeps means all day to no avail. I've been suspecting a RAM issue after a few tests this evening, and this seems to back me up. Luckily, I have more RAM on the way already (I was planning an upgrade before this beast reared its cranky head).

Comment: Great to hear that, so basically Adobe is a really RAM hungry applications. Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: It is, but I'm running 64GB (2 sticks of 32), which should be plenty for my purposes. Makes me think one (or both) of them is glitchy. Once the new RAM arrives, if that's the issue, I should be able to just swap them out and be good to go (and order 2 more sticks to make up for the glitchy ones).

Comment: You might wanna thank those sticks for choosing a perfect time to give problems hehe and hope you don’t destroy your computer while the new ones arrive. 

Comment: Well, new RAM didn't fix it. It managed to preview an AE timeline all the way to the end, which is better than the old RAM, but after I left it to play for a few minutes, the beeps are back. I can't find anything that that suggests an issue beyond the incessant beeping.

The q code on the motherboard reads AA the entire time after it finishes starting up. There seems to be no reason for this beeping.

Comment: Maybe contact support from the manufacturer(unfortunately this is the only thing that you can do), and describe this issue, also make sure that you have somehow recorded those beeps[because you know sometimes the problems that occurred before never occurs again when someone is there to fix it(happens with me a lot)].  Good luck.